# ASP.NET MVC3: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello I am Developing a ASP.NET MVC3 application and MYSQL Database accessed by entity framework. I am done with the deployment part and now i am trying to deploy it on GO DADDY server after deploying it so far every page is working fine but only in one page the following error is coming
Specified method is not supported.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.

i have tried a lot searching to find the solution of the error please help me with this

following is the snap shot of the error [image]

Answer (score 1):

You happen to have a query that results in the DbApplyExpression node in the command tree. This node is typically translated to CROSS/OUTER APPLY construct in SQL however MySQL does not support CROSS/OUTER APPLY. Most likely you will have to change your query a little bit to avoid the CROSS/OUTER APPLY. Take a look a [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896273.aspx) for more details. I also found [something](http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/entity-framework-user-request-review.html#fourth) at DevArt website that can be helpful